# django - How to query where just the described objects exist in a many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

How do I check whether there is a `thread` containing only the `sender` (user 1) and the `recipient` (user 2), and no other users.

models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    is_hidden = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='hidden_thread', blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_hidden = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='hidden_message', blank=True)
```

I tried

```
>>> Thread.objects.filter(user=user1&user2)
>>> Thread.objects.filter(user=user1|user2)
# Both gave me an error:  Unsupported operand.

# Then this
>>> Thread.objects.filter(Q(user=user1) & Q(user=user2))
# Which gave me no threads at all.

# Then this
>>> Thread.objects.filter(Q(user=user1) | Q(user=user2)).distinct()
# Gave me threads of both the users.
```

What I want is to check the thread, with the specified users only. Suppose, User 1 wants to send a message to User 2. What I want is, first check whether there is a thread between both the users. If there is, get that thread, or else create a new one. How is it possible? What is the best way to do it. Please help me. Thank you.

And please tell me what's the difference between `|` and `&`? Because I had very different results with these two.

**Edit:**

```
>>> t1 = Thread.objects.get(id=1)
>>> t1
[<User: a>,<User: b>]
>>> t2 = Thread.objects.get(id=2)
>>> t2
[<User: a>,<User: b>,<User: c>]
>>> t3 = Thread.objects.get(id=3)
>>> t3
[<User:a>,<User: c>]
>>> t4 = Thread.objects.get(id=4)
>>> t4
[<User:a>,<User:b>]
```

What I want is to get the thread where just the user `a` and user `b` exist, and no other users. In this case, it would be: `t1` and `t4`. Hope I made myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: `|` is `or`, `&` is `and`. I have no time right now to figure out how to do your actual query, but that part at least is easy to answer.

Comment: what is Q in `Thread.objects.filter(Q(user=user1) & Q(user=user2))`

Comment: Its for complex query. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
excludedUsers = Users.objects.exclude(id__in=[user1.id, user2.id])
Thread.objects.filter(users=user1).filter(users=user2).exclude(users__in=excludedUsers)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't thought of filtering the user's thread and then filter the other user again. It does return messages where both the user exist, but the threads also include other users as-well-as in that thread. I want to exclude the thread where other users exists.

Comment: you can use exclude to exclude all other users.

Comment: Did you try adding exclude at the end to remove all threads which contained other users?

Comment: Hello! I am sorry, my connection is very bad. And will you please elaborate this `[all other user objects]`. I didn't understood how to implement it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I am getting an error `id__in not defined`... :(

Comment: sorry, should be `id__in=[all other users]`. Fixed in answer

Comment: Just one more thing, can I filter for as many users I want in this way? Suppose, user1 wants to send to user2 and user 5. Can I search the thread containing just those three? Or its in a different way?

Comment: yes you can do it the same way. I think if you did `filter(users__in=[user1, user2, user 5])` would result in threads that had user1, or user2 or user5, whereas using multiple filters (eg `filter().filter()`) would select in threads that had user1 and user2 and user5. But it won't matter if you use exclude everything else, so `filter(users__in[interested users])` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose, User 1 wants to send a message to User 2. What I want is,
>   first check whether there is a thread between both the users.

Keep in mind that filter will return a list, so if there are multiple
threads between the same users, you'll get multiple results.

If you are using postgresql, you can use this syntax, which will return only distinct threads (eliminates duplicate threads):

```
threads = Message.objects.filter(sender=user1) \
                         .filter(thread__user=user2)
                         .distinct('thread')
```

If not, then you need to filter out duplicates yourself:

```
thread_ids = set(Message.objects.filter(sender=user1) \
                         .filter(thread__user=user2)
                         .values_list('thread__pk', flat=True))
threads = list(Thread.objects.get(pk=i) for i in thread_ids)

if not threads:
    # create a new thread
else:
    # Choose from one of the existing threads
```

Now that you have the unique threads with these two users; you need to eliminate all those threads that have anyone else:

```
threads.filter(user__in=[user1, user2])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using sqlite3 for now. However, when I try to execute this `threads = list(Thread.objects.get(pk=i) for i in thread_ids)`, I get an error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or number, not a 'tuple'`

Comment: Thank you. And yes that threads does include both the user, but also the other users. Please see my edit. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I have a feeling there might be a cleaner way to do this through a custom manager.

Comment: `threads.filter(user__in=[user1, user2])` will return threads which contain *at least* these two users. What needs to happen is `threads.exclude(user__in=[all other users]`